# Error in evaluating this limit?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, fluid-dynamics

No matter how I look at this limit, it looks like it should evaluate to $0$. Am I missing some rule about limits with differentials?

The limit is from page 19 of the third edition of Viscous Fluid Flow by Frank White.

$$d\alpha = \lim_{dt->0}\left(\arctan\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dxdt}{dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dxdt}\right) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt$$

My best guess is that the author is assuming $dx >> \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and then using the small-angle approximation, but that is not mentioned in the text.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It would also be useful if you would [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), and at the minimum say where in White's book this is found.

Comment: saulspatz, DMcMor, thank you for the advice. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: How can the answer be in terms of $dt$ when $dt \to 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not so much a typo as there is a seeming abuse of notation.  It seems that White is using $$\lim_{dt->0}\left(\arctan\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx\,dt}{dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx\,dt}\right) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt$$ to mean that $$\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx\,dt}{dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx\,dt}\right)\sim \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt\quad\text{ as } dt\to 0.$$  This is relatively straightforward to show.  First, rewrite
\begin{align}
\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx\,dt}{dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx\,dt}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt}{1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dt}\right).
\end{align}

Then, using $$\tan(\theta) \sim \theta\quad\text{ as }\theta \to 0 \implies \arctan(\theta) \sim \theta\quad\text{ as }\theta \to 0,$$  as well as

$$\frac{ax}{1+bx}\sim ax\quad\text{ as }x\to 0, 
$$
we have that

\begin{alignat}{2}
\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt}{1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dt}\right) &\sim \frac{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt}{1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dt} &&\quad\text{ as }dt\to 0\\
&\sim \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dt&&\quad\text{ as } dt\to 0.
\end{alignat}

Comment: Thank you! That's kind of what I was thinking, but I couldn't get over the notation.